# How to use django admin display some specific order data

Tags: django

I have model below

```
class SynonymQuery(models.Model):                                                
    original_query = models.CharField(max_length=30,verbose_name = "query")                                  
    insert_time = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

admin below

```
class synonym_queryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):       
     ordering = ('update_time','original_query')
```

data
1.bcd time
2.abc time
3.bcd time

if No.1 data is insert last time, I want to show data all the same original_query as No.1 in the header lines.

I try to use ordering function, but result are incorrect.

Comment: sorry my english

Comment: what is `update_time`? Maybe you want to use `insert_time` in the ordering tuple.

Comment: Do you want to effectively 'group by' `original_query`, then order by the most recent query in each group?

Comment: @FraserES yes you are right,but after 'group by' , some data can not display, I want to show all data.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to literally use a SQL group by, I just wanted to confirm what you meant. I'll have a think and get back to you when I have time :)